# JQuery Dynamic Content After Same Domain Redirect

Tags: jquery, redirect, dynamic, reset

I have a button that gets appended to all visible, specified DIVs.

I want my script to run again (append buttons) when the page is dynamically filled with new DIVs.

The website features a transparent redirect so that music can keep playing while you browse other pages.

I'm relatively new and I've been searching everywhere for this problem, but no luck!

Any hack/help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you using in terms of making the page change, jQuery, pure javascript, AJAX?

Comment: A single page application/website? There are several libraries that you can use, Backbone, Ember, AngularJS and ... Some of them also support HTML5 History API.

Comment: I'm using JQuery to add the buttons with .append() and .button() and .click()
Can JQuery catch any redirect event? Like I just don't know how to check when the page gets changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   // do your magic here
});
```

Comment: The hash actually doesn't change but I found an event to commandeer hehe